# C# IndexOf in special persian character

Tags: c#, indexof

in persian/arabic character, some character used optional  on top or bottom of other character like  `ِ َ  ّ  ُ`.

in my example if i use this character, indexOf not found  my word. consider that persian/arabic is rtl language.

for example:

```
منّم => م + ن + ّ + م

C#:

"منّم".IndexOf("من");
return -1

javascript:
```

```js
var index=    ' منّم '.indexOf('من');
console.log(index);
```

what happened in C#. anyone can explain this?

Comment: "what?" - what?

Comment: So c# returns a different result than javascript and you want to know why?

Comment: @ ZoharPeled yes. C# not find index of my word

Comment: Have you tried using the overload for [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) that uses a `StringComparison`?

Comment: @AselS i use .net framework 4. this not exist in this version

Comment: dont do "string". You can't put the stringname in "

Comment: What is the expected index amir? 1?

Comment: @AselS in my app, cusomer can search in persian documents. and they search on simliar cases and report bug for me.

Comment: Shaddah is a nonspacing mark. منّ and من are lexicographically not the same thing. splitting ّ  from ن for the search as a default behavior is arguable. OPINIONS: I would consider the Javascript implementation of IndexOf wrong since I think splitting marks from letter is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By passing in [`StringComparison.Ordinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8) as an argument to the overloaded [`String.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_), you could have also done the following:

```
"منّم".IndexOf("من", StringComparison.Ordinal); // returns 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Specifying [`CompareOptions.Ordinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netframework-4.8)  as an option should work, together with the [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) method of [`CompareInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo?view=netframework-4.8).

```
CompareInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo;
string str = "منّم";
Console.WriteLine(info.IndexOf(str, "من", CompareOptions.Ordinal));
```

Output is 0.

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DMaxVK) if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: thanks. yes it return correct value. but what is diffrence between this method with string IndexOf? are you know that?

Comment: @amir110 The topic is well explained in the links I've posted, take a look at the Remarks section of ```CompareInfo.IndexOf```.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn about the different methods that .Net uses to compare/match strings.

[Best Practices for Using Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#the_details_of_string_comparison)

> Some overloads with default parameters (those that search for a Char
>   in the string instance) perform an ordinal comparison, whereas others
>   (those that search for a string in the string instance) are
>   culture-sensitive. It is difficult to remember which method uses which
>   default value, and easy to confuse the overloads.

The section [String Operations that Use the Invariant Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#string-operations-that-use-the-invariant-culture) gives a short explanation about combining characters.